# Unmet dependencies in ros-electric-desktop-full installation

Tags: ros, opencv, vision-opencv, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I come up with the following error while installing ros-electric-desktop-full:

**Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ros-electric-desktop-full: Depends: ros-electric-vision-opencv (= 1.6.8-s1321009367~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-electric-image-pipeline (= 1.6.3-s1321009993~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-electric-image-transport-plugins (= 1.4.2-s1321009887~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages**

So I went ahead and tried to install ros-electric-vision-opencv on its own using "sudo apt-get install ros-electric-vision-opencv", but had the following error message:

**Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ros-electric-vision-opencv: Depends: libopencv2.3-dev (= 2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-8~lucid) but 2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-6~lucid is to be installed
E: Broken packages**

Is there a problem with the dependencies for libopencv2.3-dev?

Thank you!

Edit1: Looking into the problem further, I noticed that http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/lists/ros-lucid-electric_lucid_main_i386_Packages (updated today) uses 2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-8~lucid for libopencv2.3-dev. However,http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/binary-i386/Packages uses 2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-6~lucid. I think this is causing the problem. Should this be reported as a bug?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11915/unmet-dependencies-in-ros-electric-desktop-full-installation/) by [esha_umn](https://answers.ros.org/users/1366/esha_umn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2011-11-11

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [esha_umn](https://answers.ros.org/users/1366/esha_umn/) on 2011-11-14**:
The problem with dependencies has been sorted out. I managed to install electric-desktop-full successfully today.

**Comment by [Daniel Canelhas](https://answers.ros.org/users/1180/daniel-canelhas/) on 2011-11-11**:
I found this to be the case, as well: The following packages have unmet dependencies:ros-electric-eigen : Depends: libeigen3-dev (= 3.0.1-1+ros4~natty) but 3.0.2-3+natty1 is to be installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem as the OP (lucid and oneiric). The problem seems to (now) be fixed for me by switching from Freiburg mirror to the main mirror. So it might be fixed upstream but changes need a while to settle down.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2011-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1